# Integer in Array returns null

Tags: plugins, array

Im using EDD_Fees class for adding extra fee to products, Iv’e used this class before and it works like charm but now i can’t figure it out why amount equals to 0 (it seems returning null) But when i `echo` shows the integer value.
Here is my full class code

```
$feeid_gen = date("Ydhis") . $download_id;
            function cencored_function() {
            // Additional Services Price START here
                    $cencored_fee = array(
            'amount'      => $int_val,
            'label'       => 'hbbl',    
            'id'          => $feeid_gen,    
            'no_tax'      => false,
            'type'        => 'fee',
            'download_id' => $download_id,
            'price_id'    => NULL   
                );
            EDD()->fees->add_fee( $cencored_fee);
            /// Additional Services Price END here
            }
            add_action( 'init', 'cencored_function' );
            cencored_function(); // Runned
```

Comment: "But when i echo shows the integer value." — If you're `echo`ing to debug, use `var_dump()` instead, as that will show you the variable's type as well as its value.

Comment: @PatJ it shows int(199) :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where "$int_val" is defined, may be it is defined outside the scope of "cencored_function", it won't work if this is the case.

Comment: Oh how its possible i didn't notice that, ThankYou